# Is There A Better Way To Delete Vertexes In JanusGraph?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, java-17, graph-traversal, orientdb3.0

Is there a way to just `drop()` all of the Vertexes in JanusGraph like OrientDB?

`g.V().drop().iterate()` takes about 2 minutes to traverse through 70005 basic vertices.
[JanusGraph's JanusGraph (interface)](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-core/latest/index.html) extends from [JanusGraph's Transaction](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-core/0.3.1/org/janusgraph/core/Transaction.html); *not* [Tinkerpop-Gremlin's Transaction](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Transaction.java). Instead, its from [Tinkerpop-Gremlin's Graph (interface)](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Graph.html).

```json
2023-05-10 10:21:19,726 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:9042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2023-05-10 10:21:19,803 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.DefaultMavenCoordinates.main] ::     DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.15.0
2023-05-10 10:21:20,226 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.t.Clock.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::   Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-05-10 10:21:20,474 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::     [JanusGraph Session|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=4bb4c89e)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
2023-05-10 10:21:20,688 [INFO] [o.j.g.i.UniqueInstanceIdRetriever.main] ::   Generated unique-instance-id=c0a8563c288-rmt-lap-win201
2023-05-10 10:21:20,703 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:9042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2023-05-10 10:21:20,728 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.t.Clock.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::   Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-05-10 10:21:20,760 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::     [JanusGraph Session|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=1ec16fcd)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
2023-05-10 10:21:20,775 [INFO] [o.j.d.c.ExecutorServiceBuilder.main] ::  Initiated fixed thread pool of size 40
2023-05-10 10:21:20,876 [INFO] [o.j.g.d.StandardJanusGraph.main] ::  Gremlin script evaluation is disabled
2023-05-10 10:21:20,901 [INFO] [o.j.d.l.k.KCVSLog.main] ::   Loaded unidentified ReadMarker start time 2023-05-10T15:21:20.901765Z into org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller@f1d0004
2023-05-10 10:21:20,955 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-10 10:21:22,284 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    g.V().count().next():  70005
2023-05-10 10:21:22,287 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-10 10:23:09,867 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-10 10:23:10,914 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    g.V().count().next():  0
```

```java
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql").set("storage.hostname", "localhost:9042").open();
        GraphTraversalSource g = janusGraph.traversal();
        logger.info("g.V().count().next():\t" + g.V().count().next());
        g.V().drop().iterate();
        logger.info("g.V().count().next():\t" + g.V().count().next());
```

---

In OrientDB and Neo4j, I can just run 2 methods: `g.V().drop()` + `orientGraph.commit()` and its done instantly.

```java
        OrientGraph orientGraph = OrientGraph.open(configuration);
        GraphTraversalSource g = orientGraph.traversal();
        g.V().drop();
        orientGraph.commit();
```

But when I try this in JanusGraph, `g.V().drop()` + `g.tx().commit()` does not seem to work.
I've even tried other variations and cannot seem to stumble my way into the right process of steps.
70003 vertices before and 70003 vertices after.

```json
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55234', transport: 'socket'
2023-05-10 08:05:21,875 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:9042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2023-05-10 08:05:21,961 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.DefaultMavenCoordinates.main] ::     DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.15.0
2023-05-10 08:05:26,093 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.t.Clock.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::   Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-05-10 08:05:28,441 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::     [JanusGraph Session|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=3954ab39)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
2023-05-10 08:05:28,713 [INFO] [o.j.g.i.UniqueInstanceIdRetriever.main] ::   Generated unique-instance-id=c0a8563c24184-rmt-lap-win201
2023-05-10 08:05:28,731 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:9042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2023-05-10 08:05:28,758 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.t.Clock.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::   Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-05-10 08:05:30,236 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::     [JanusGraph Session|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=31297484)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
2023-05-10 08:05:30,249 [INFO] [o.j.d.c.ExecutorServiceBuilder.main] ::  Initiated fixed thread pool of size 40
2023-05-10 08:05:30,350 [INFO] [o.j.g.d.StandardJanusGraph.main] ::  Gremlin script evaluation is disabled
2023-05-10 08:05:30,374 [INFO] [o.j.d.l.k.KCVSLog.main] ::   Loaded unidentified ReadMarker start time 2023-05-10T13:05:30.374192Z into org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller@378f002a
2023-05-10 08:05:30,437 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-10 08:05:31,861 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    g.V().count().next():  70003
2023-05-10 08:05:31,866 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-10 08:05:33,045 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    g.V().count().next():  70003
2023-05-10 08:05:34,523 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-10 08:05:34,530 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    vp[empty]
2023-05-10 08:05:34,531 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    vp[empty]
2023-05-10 08:05:34,534 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    vp[empty]
...
2023-05-10 08:05:34,530 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    vp[empty]
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55234', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

```java
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql").set("storage.hostname", "localhost:9042").open();
        GraphTraversalSource g = janusGraph.traversal();
        logger.info("g.V().count().next():\t" + g.V().count().next());
//        g.V().drop().iterate();
        g.V().drop();
        g.tx().commit();
        logger.info("g.V().count().next():\t" + g.V().count().next());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@HadoopMarc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16598470/hadoopmarc) for [working through this issue with me](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/discussions/3769)!
[Ended up using a while-loop to handle JVM memory issues.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76229522/11705601)

```java
        while (g.V().count().next()>0)
            g.V().limit(10000).drop().iterate();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small graph `g.V().drop()` should be just fine. However your `commit` looks wrong. You need a `g.tx().commit()` not a commit from the management API.

If you are using Cassandra as the back end, especially if you have a large graph, and don't need the graph anymore just drop the whole keyspace and start over. That should be a lot faster than deleting all the vertices.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with my JanusGraph.

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Comment: Vertex-Dropping with `g.V().drop()` then `g.tx().commit()`. 70003 records before; 70003 records after.

Comment: In your example code the one with `iterate()` is commented out? You need the terminal step to be there.

Comment: Tried it originally with iterate and any number of combinations. `iterate()` was the first thing I tried and that doesn't work in this example.